# Delphi Android app - Detect if device has internet connection

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, internet-connection, delphi-10.1-berlin

How I can detect if Android device has internet connection (WiFi or mobile internet) from my FireMonkey application.
I know I can use Indy components ... try Ping google.com ... and wait for exceptionon on timeout but I want to know If exist some "nice" native solution for Android,

I using Delphi XE10.1 Berlin

Comment: personnaly i didn't find a better solution, simply put try .. except around all the http call to catch no internet exception and show message to end user, because anyway even if the mobile say it's connected to the wifi, it's not mean the internet is working, or the mobile network can be so much slow that it's not work  ... if you find better solution, please write it :)

Comment: I tested it and it works fine !

Comment: If only there was a "dial tone" on the internet :)